# Combine 2 Date Rows To 2 Columns In 1 Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 1 table with time records and type 1 and 2. I want them to combine into 1 row. [image]

I am expecting log_type 1 with no log_type 2 partner. Expected result would be:

```
A | 2017-02-01 08:00:00.000 | 2017-02-01 08:10:00.000
A | 2017-02-01 08:30:00.000 |
A | 2017-02-01 08:40:00.000 | 2017-02-01 08:50:00.000
A | 2017-02-01 09:00:00.000 |
```

Here is my script:

```
create table test_time
(
    person varchar(30)
    ,log_time datetime
    ,log_type int
)

insert into test_time
values
('A','2017-02-01 8:00:00',1)
,('A','2017-02-01 8:10:00',2)
,('A','2017-02-01 8:30:00',1)
,('A','2017-02-01 8:40:00',1)
,('A','2017-02-01 8:50:00',2)
,('A','2017-02-01 9:00:00',1)
```

Also, I should be able to handle other persons. I already tried ROW_NUMBER but I'm stuck. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try following query (untested):

```
SELECT y.*
FROM (
    SELECT t.person, t.log_time, t.log_type, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.person ORDER BY t.log_time) - t.log_type AS group_num
    FROM dbo.MyTable AS t
) x
PIVOT( MAX(x.log_time) FOR x.log_type IN ([1], [2])) y
ORDER BY y.person, y.group_num
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put the results in *one* column.  I would just define a second column with the appropriate value.

You appear to want `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when next_log_status = 2 then next_log_time end) as log_time_2
from (select t.*, 
             lead(log_time) over (partition by person order by log_time) as next_log_time,
             lead(log_status) over (partition by person order by log_time) as next_log_status
      from test_time t
     ) t
where log_status = 1;
```

If you really want the two dates in one column, you can concatenate them together.  That does not seem useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

With subquery:

```
select 
    t1.person,
    t1.log_time,
    (
         select top 1 test_time
         from test_time t2 
         where t1.person = t2.person 
             and t2.log_type = 2
             and t1.test_time <= t2.test_time
         order by test_time asc) log_time2
from test_time t1
where t1.log_type = 1
```

Comment: row number 2 column 2 should be null. your query used 3rd row value